# Messy partitions: How do I fix my HDD and SSD partitions from a USB?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, kernel, gparted

So after finding out I gave my external HDD 250 MB instead of 250 GB I tried to fix it by changing the partitions around with some popular software. 
Told me to restart my PC.
Now every time I try to get onto any of my drives I get that famous Kernel panic error.

I've tried "Try Ubuntu without install" and "Boot-Repair".
First one still gives me the error and Boot-Repair said it succeeded.

I'm pretty sure this is because the partition with the boot-flag got the wrong file system.

I didn't know at the time so I tried to set all partitions on ext2 except the swap.

I can get to grub rescue and I have boot able USB's at hand.

My question is. How do I fix my HDD and SSD partitions from a USB?

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include "SOLVED" or an answer, please post a proper answer and accept it.

Comment: The "edit" was made before posting. But I see were you want me to go.

Comment: Thank you for participating and following our site's guidelines. Welcome on [ubuntu.se]! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading my own question I got a new search term were I found my answer. I'm still posting this so people in my situation don't give up on their drives. You can download GParted iso file from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/) (230MB) and use Rufus to "burn" it to you're USB. Follow directions [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/file-folder/fl/burn-iso-usb.htm). Boot from the USB and resize the partitions with right file system.